# How can I iPhone restore in iTunes without upgrading iOS?

Tags: ios, itunes, iphone, restore

I am trying to restore a set of my iPhone5C backups I made in iTunes to my iPhone4S. My iPhone4S is still running on iOS 7.0.4. I don't want to upgrade it because iOS8 on iPhone4S will almost be unusable (the current iOS7 is bad enough on iPhone4S).

I have tried doing this directly in iTunes using its restore function, but when I do so, iTunes forces me to update my iOS to 8.3. If I refuse to upgrade, the restore function will abort and I cannot continue with my restore from there.

How can I perform the restore in iTunes without having to upgrade my iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Restoring from another device's backup will update to the latest iOS the restored device can use.

The only way would be to restore from a backup initially made from that same device, using that iOS.

Comment: Really, I have to upgrade to iOS8 before I can do any sort of restore on my iPhone4S? I wish I could upgrade but that iOS8 will render my iPhone4S unusable. :(

Comment: You can restore it to its own backup, but not that of another device